# How to copy lookup_id from Table1 to Table2 with INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a student learning SQL Server and using the management studio to normalize a db which started as a single table.

I now have Table1 with 80,000 rows containing ID, CategoryDescription, etc... with many repeated CateogoryDescriptions.

Table2 has a list of all of the CategoryDescriptions and a DescriptionID column which was created using SELECT DISTINCT. It has about 100 rows.

I want to copy the DescriptionID values from Table2 into Table 1 so that I can delete the large CategoryDescription column and replace it with a link to the lookup table.

The following generates the expected data (a single column of 80,000 ids):

```
SELECT TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames.Con_ID
FROM TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames
JOIN TEST.dbo.MainTable
ON TEST.dbo.MainTable.CONCESSION = TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames.Con_Name
```

However, when I add the INSERT INTO...

```
INSERT INTO TEST.dbo.MainTable
SELECT TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames.Con_ID
FROM TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames
JOIN TEST.dbo.MainTable
ON TEST.dbo.MainTable.CONCESSION = TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames.Con_Name
```

I get "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."  To clarify, there is no column in MainTable called Con_ID.  I thought that perhaps that was the problem, but when I added one (and verified the same data type) I get the same error.

Comment: could you try naming your tables and columns a bit more descriptively. Oh, and get rid of the underscores!

Comment: Sure.  They started that way, but I thought it would be more useful if i made them more generic (as suggested).  Underscores are copied from examples I am following, but I get your point.  Makes typing harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be inserting new records as you want to update existing ones.

You can do:

```
UPDATE TEST.dbo.MainTable
SET TEST.dbo.MainTable.Con_ID = C.Con_ID
FROM TEST.dbo.MainTable T
INNER JOIN TEST.dbo.LU_ConNames C
ON T.CONCESSION = C.Con_Name
```

Some reading on that topicon [MSDN - UPDATE syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#OtherTables)

Comment: Thanks.  This works great, but you are introducing syntax that is new to me and I don't understand. <br/>  SET TEST.dbo.MainTable.Con_ID = ***C.Con_ID***  FROM TEST.dbo.MainTable ***T***  Similarly your use of ***C*** and ***C.Con_Name***  I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction to understand these.  (Im still figureing out how to comment!!)

Comment: Added a link to the relevant section on MSDN.

Comment: Ok - I just read up on Alias's and though your syntax doesn't use AS, I can see that it must be inferred.  Also that you can use an alias before it is defined!

Comment: Yes, `AS` is optional. Even if you do `SELECT T.column from table1 T` you use alias this way.